# Symfony 2 DQL query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have this query in Symfony 2. It works great but I was wondering if it was possible to make something cleaner.

I'm new to Symfony and QueryBuilder and I couldn't get to do something that works with the queryBuilder.

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT t '.
    'FROM MyBundle:Task t '.
    'WHERE t.folder IN '.
            '(SELECT f.id '.
            'FROM MyBundle:Folder f '.
            'WHERE f.priority = '.$prio.
            ' AND f.user IN '.
              '(SELECT u.id '.
                'FROM MyBundle:User u '.
                'WHERE u.id ='.$user->getId().'))');
```

The scheme is simple
A User has Many Folders, a Folder has many Tasks and I m looking for all tasks for one user.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you have entity relation for this three entity? if yes try this

```
$em->createQuery('SELECT t FROM MyBundle:Task t'
                . 'JOIN t.folder f'
                . 'JOIN f.user u'
                . 'WHERE u.id=:id')
                ->setParameter('id', $user->getId());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I just had to add some spacings and a parameter for the priority but it works.

Comment: Or with the builder `$em->createQueryBuilder('t')->join('t.folder', 'f')->join('f.user', 'u')->where('u.id', ':id')->setParameter('id', $user->getId())`

Comment: I had to rearrange it a little bit but thanks to you I learned a bit more about this kind of syntax. The right syntax for the where is 
`where('u.id = :id')`
Thanks ;-)